# modify the Access policy SNS for inpector

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-sns, aws-access-policy

how to modify the sns topic policy to permission to access to aws inspector in us-east-1?Assessment Templates has no permission to sns topic.
I got this error:

```
The Inspector Account was denied access to the requested topic Grant account xxxxxxxxx permission to publish to the topic arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:xxxxxxxx:inspector
```

```
{
  "Version": "2008-10-17",
  "Id": "__default_policy_ID",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "__default_statement_ID",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": [
        "SNS:GetTopicAttributes",
        "SNS:SetTopicAttributes",
        "SNS:AddPermission",
        "SNS:RemovePermission",
        "SNS:DeleteTopic",
        "SNS:Subscribe",
        "SNS:ListSubscriptionsByTopic",
        "SNS:Publish",
        "SNS:Receive"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:xxxxxxxx:inspector",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "AWS:SourceOwner": "xxxxxxxxx"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/inspector/latest/userguide/inspector_assessments.html#sns-topic) on AWS has exactly what you need to do:

> **To set up an SNS topic for notifications**
>
> Create an SNS topic. See Tutorial: Creating an Amazon SNS Topic. When
>   you create the topic, expand the Access policy - optional section.
>   Then do the following to permit the assessment to send messages to the
>   topic:
>
> For Choose method, choose Basic.
>
> For Define who can publish messages to the topic, choose Only the
>   specified AWS accounts, and then enter the ARN for the account in the
>   Region that you're creating the topic in:
>
> US East (Ohio) - arn:aws:iam::646659390643:root
>
> US East (N. Virginia) - arn:aws:iam::316112463485:root
>
> US West (N. California) - arn:aws:iam::166987590008:root
>
> US West (Oregon) - arn:aws:iam::758058086616:root
>
> Asia Pacific (Mumbai) - arn:aws:iam::162588757376:root
>
> Asia Pacific (Seoul) - arn:aws:iam::526946625049:root
>
> Asia Pacific (Sydney) - arn:aws:iam::454640832652:root
>
> Asia Pacific (Tokyo) - arn:aws:iam::406045910587:root
>
> Europe (Frankfurt) - arn:aws:iam::537503971621:root
>
> Europe (Ireland) - arn:aws:iam::357557129151:root
>
> Europe (London) - arn:aws:iam::146838936955:root
>
> Europe (Stockholm) - arn:aws:iam::453420244670:root
>
> AWS GovCloud (US-East) - arn:aws-us-gov:iam::206278770380:root
>
> AWS GovCloud (US-West) - arn:aws-us-gov:iam::850862329162:root
>
> For Define who can subscribe to this topic, choose Only the specified
>   AWS accounts, and then enter the ARN for the account in the Region
>   that you're creating the topic in.

Answer (score 1):

I have removed the condition block

"Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "AWS:SourceOwner": "xxxxxxxxx"
        }
      }

Now works for me.

Comment: Having this similar error but the odd part is the account number listed isn't even one of our accounts.  3161********.  Very odd.  I removed the IAM SNS condition you mentioned and it still did not work.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your SNS access policy. It worked for me.

**Note:** My AWS Inspector is configured in Oregon so that I am using "arn:aws:iam::758058086616:root"

[Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/inspector/latest/userguide/inspector_assessments.html).

And my SNS topic is already in the Oregon region.

```
{
  "Sid": "CustomInspectorPolicy",
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Principal": {
    "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::758058086616:root"
  },
  "Action": "SNS:Publish",
  "Resource": "arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:<YOUR AWS ACCOUNT NO>:<YOUR SNS TOPIC>"
}
```